# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' on app_store_scraper

Tags: python, ios, web-scraping

So I try to **scrape** app store review by using library app_store_scraper but when I run the code which exactly like the doc for scrape an app it throw and error.When I read the doc and github repository it already closed.Anyone can help me with the error?

```
2021-10-12 10:37:52,596 [INFO] Base - Searching for app id
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3441, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-788606d20c80>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/PC/PycharmProjects/iosreview/main.py', wdir='C:/Users/PC/PycharmProjects/iosreview')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.2.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.2.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/PC/PycharmProjects/iosreview/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    myjne = AppStore(country="id", app_name="My JNE")
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\app_store_scraper\app_store.py", line 23, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\app_store_scraper\base.py", line 47, in __init__
    app_id = self.search_id()
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\app_store_scraper\base.py", line 175, in search_id
    app_id = re.search(pattern, self._response.text).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

My code is only

```
from app_store_scraper import AppStore
myjne = AppStore(country="id", app_name="tiktok")
myjne.review(how_many=20)
```

Comment: It looks like you get empty array when you make a request. Try to make an exception to avoid it.

Comment: Seems like your package: https://github.com/cowboy-bebug/app-store-scraper is no longer maintained and likely not working anymore.

Comment: Deprecated Programming Library is no longer working/supported.